# Работа с несколькими формами

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

```
private:System::Void button1_Click(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e)
{
    Form2().ShowDialog();
    //Form2^ form2 = gcnew Form2(); form2->Show();
}

private:System::Void pictureBox1_Paint(System::Object ^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs ^ e)
{
    if (Form2().Rectangle->CheckState == CheckState::Checked)
    {
        Graphics ^ g = e->Graphics;
        Pen ^ BluePen = gcnew Pen(Color::Blue, 1);
        g->DrawRectangle(BluePen, 50, 50, 100, 100);
    };
    Update();
}
```

В Form2 есть два CheckBox(Rectangle, Circle). Как заставить рисовать в Form1 после нажатия на Fom2 нужной кнопки и чтобы при закрытии Form2 сохранились выбраные параметры?

Comment: Ну и сочетание вы выбрали: WinForms и C++/CLI!

Отставить мазохизм! Перебегайте на кошерный C# с WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Как мне кажется, нужно pictureBox1 создавать на первой форме, и обработчик события pictureBox1_Paint - соответственно там же. Далее в обработчике события (уже первой формы) - проверка условия на отмеченные чекбоксы второй формы:

```
private:System::Void pictureBox1_Paint(System::Object ^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs ^ e)
{
    if (form2.Rectangle->Checked == true)
    {
        Graphics ^ g = e->Graphics;
        Pen ^ BluePen = gcnew Pen(Color::Blue, 1);
        g->DrawRectangle(BluePen, 50, 50, 100, 100);
    };
    Update();
}
```

А чекнутые или нет - это вроде бы должно сохраняться. На крайний случай - объявишь переменную типа `bool` во второй форме и присвоишь ей значение `checkBox->Checked`